# GUI for receiving and displaying data being sent from server using python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, user-interface, tkinter

I am attempting to receive and display data in Realtime in a  GUI, however I can't figure out how to make the program refresh itself to display new incoming data.

```
import socket
import json
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
person={}

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))
print("connected")
def Main():
     while (True):
        data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if data:
            person = json.loads(data)

master.minsize(width=450, height=450)
master.wm_title("Stack Problem")



scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.place(x=420, y=150)
terminal_listbox = tk.Listbox(master, width=65, height=13)
terminal_listbox.place(x=5, y=100)
scrollbar.config(command=terminal_listbox.yview)
master.update()
terminal_listbox.see(tk.END)
terminal_listbox.insert(tk.END, person)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using a while loop in tkinter will cause the GUI to become unresponsive. Use the .after method to schedule a function to be called after a time delay. You can use this to create a function that runs periodically.

Comment: To add on to scotty, perhaps create a function that DOES have a while loop but runs in a thread (that way the tkinter window will not freeze up) and when data is receive, call a helper method to update the GUI with whatever data was received